# Is Defining window mandatory for unbounded pcollection

Tags: apache-beam

New to beam/flink and would appreciate assistance in this issue.
I have a pipeline that reads from kafka avro message does some object transformation and writes again to kafka. ו did not define any window since currently we would like to handle each event separately with no aggregation.
I wonder if this correct. From what i understand in the docs seem like we cannot use the default behaviour and define some kind of window and relevant triggers.

Is my understanding correct?
Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a windowing strategy for a pipeline, it will automatically run on a global window. Since no aggregations or such are to be made, this is ok.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/notebooks/tour-of-beam/windowing.ipynb says:

> All pipelines use the GlobalWindow by default. This is a single window that covers the entire PCollection.
> In many cases, especially for batch pipelines, this is what we want since we want to analyze all the data that we have.
>
> ℹ️ GlobalWindow is not very useful in a streaming pipeline unless you only need element-wise transforms. Aggregations, like GroupByKey and Combine, need to process the entire window, but a streaming pipeline has no end, so they would never finish.